# Subtract 1,000 years from a date

Tags: oracle, date

We have records with dates far into the future (i.e. 3/9/3006) which are causing issues. Is there a way to update a date field to -1,000 years? Currently I have to look up the values of ten date fields in each record and then update each one like this. (This is Cerner CCL but you should be able to understand it). I can run PL/SQL in SQL Developer.

`set ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM = format("March 09, 2006 15:47:14", "@LONGDATETIME")`
`,ARRIVE_DT_TM = format("March 30, 2006 07:44:00", "@LONGDATETIME")`
`…`

I wasn't able to find anything in Oracle that would work like this:
`ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM = ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM - 1000 years`

I tried this but it doesn't work:
`set EST_ARRIVE_DT_TM = EST_ARRIVE_DT_TM - interval '1000' year`

Comment: set EST_ARRIVE_DT_TM = add_months(EST_ARRIVE_DT_TM, -12000)

Comment: Let me guess: you stored date values as **strings** instead of proper `DATE` values...

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't too helpful. HOW does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle there is a function add_months(<date_field>,-12*number of years) , This will subtract the number of months(-) should help.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt should work with only a small modification. You only said "it didn't work", but you didn't explain what that means. I assume it's what I noticed on my system: the interval literal throws an error about "precision too small".

If you read the documentation, you will see that an interval literal takes an optional parameter for "precision". Your number of years, 1000, is a four-digit number, which is more than the default precision of the interval literal (the default is just 2 digits).

All you have to do is to give the precision as an explicit argument. Like so:

```
select sysdate as old_date, sysdate - interval '1000' year(4) as new_date
from   dual;


OLD_DATE   NEW_DATE  
---------- ----------
2021-01-13 1021-01-13
```

(Note that I set up my session to show dates in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.)

Notice the (4) in the interval literal:  year(4) means I am specifying a four-digit number of years (1000 is a four-digit number).

Link to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598

Comment: This worked! I forgot to include the error which was ORA-01873. Thanks.

Comment: Looking closer it ran but didn't work. The year dropped 220 years, not 1,000. maybe 1,000 is out of range.  
Before: ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM = September 14, 2020 15:42:19  
  
    Update encounter    
    set ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM = ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM - interval '1000' year(4)    

After: ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM = September 14, 1800 15:42:19

Comment: @KennethSalstrom - Obviously not. I included a test case in my answer already: SYSDATE is now, and subtracting 1000 years resulted in a date in calendar year 1021. Please try MY example on your system and see what result you get. If you can confirm that my example works exactly as it did for me, that will give you important information; namely, that you may be doing something else wrong, or there is another issue. The problem isn't the "subtract 1000 years" operation, but something else (IF my example works perfectly on your system). Please try and let us know what happens.

Comment: For example: You may have a *trigger* on your table, which intercepts any "inserted" or "updated" date, it checks the year, and it replaces it with 1800 if it's less than that. Or who knows what else (really a huge number of similar possible explanations that have **nothing** to do with the simple process of subtracting 1000 years, even though they may be *triggered* by it).

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to format nicely. The select works but the update doesn't. There must be something in the system restraining it to 1800.
```
select to_char(ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ,to_char(ACTIVE_STATUS_DT_TM - interval '1000' year(4), 'MM/DD/YYYY')  
from encounter  
where ENCNTR_ID =     43799248.00  
``
08/25/2020 08/25/1020

Comment: @KennethSalstrom - so, the easy thing to check is to see if there are any triggers on your table; that seems to me like the simplest explanation. Other than that, HOW are you executing your UPDATE statement? Can you try in the simplest interface (like SQL\*Plus) and see if you get the same behavior? That could tell you where the problem is most likely to be. But, in any case, none of this has anything to do with your original question anymore, which - as far as I understand - is now completely answered.

Comment: I've got this working. I was altering the date in our test system by -1000 which was being set to 1800. I bumped a few dates to +1000 and then -1000 and that worked. Why the system set the dates to 1800 doesn't matter as I don't need to go back that far.